# Amazon S3 file empty after change Content Distribution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am fairly new to working with the AWS Ruby SDK and I ran into an odd situation.

I have files that I upload directly to S3 so I can avoid passing them through my server. I keep track of the files by their AWS key on my server when they are uploaded, however I want to change the content disposition so as to set the filename for download.

I have used the following in one of my rails workers:

```
component.s3_object.put(content_disposition: "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=#{component.name}")
```

Which correctly sets the Content-Disposition metadata for the file but when it does the file no longer has any data, the file size drops to 0 Bytes. What am I doing wrong that is corrupting the files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to specify the `body` param?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method

Comment: Nice catch sir, you are correct. I assumed that the S3 request name of `PUT` conformed with REST API convention in which the params that are passed would only be updated on the object instead of being set. 

Do you know how one might push an update to an object instead of writing/overwriting an object.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  Could try the move or copy with updated content disposition.

Comment: Yeah thats what its looking like I will end up doing. Thanks for your help.